# Postman test - how to search an array for a list of values without defining index

Tags: arrays, loops, postman

I'm trying to create a Postman test, and I have a response which includes an array that returns 50+ values I need to verify, and so far I've been writing a test line item for each.

```
var searchJSON = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["check_group_name1"] = /name1/.test(searchJSON.Entity.Group[0].Name);
tests["check_group_name2"] = /name2/.test(searchJSON.Entity.Group[1].Name);
tests["check_group_name3"] = /name3/.test(searchJSON.Entity.Group[2].Name);
```

Problem is, if/when this API changes, it will be a nightmare to maintain and update each index value.

Is there a way to use a loop to verify 50+ values, without depending on each index position in the array?  Is it even possible?

This is what a sample response looks like:

```
{
 "Entity":{
   "Group": [
     {
      "Name": "name1",
     },
     {
      "Name: "name2",
     },
     {
      "Name: "name3",
     },
   ],
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you start with the array

```
[
   {'Name': 'name1'},
   {'Name': 'name2'},
   {'Name': 'name3'}
]
```

You can pull all the values out into a list like this

```
string json = @"
[
   {'Name': 'name1'},
   {'Name': 'name2'},
   {'Name': 'name3'}
]";

JArray arr = JArray.Parse(json);
List<string> names = arr.Select(token => token.SelectToken("Name").Value<string>()).ToList();
```

Then you can iterate through the values and check them with whatever test logic you like.

Comment: I got "JArray is not defined" error